# Cut and paste in Finder copies to wrong folder

Tags: finder

I have highlighted the *bin* folder :

[image]

And then from the *Finder* menu have selected _Edit | Paste

The result?  the three files are pasted to the *parent* directory of the *bin* folder. This is repeatable.  Why is that happening?

**Update**  It appears that if I *right click* on the *bin* folder then the Paste works properly.  That is just *wrong* to behave differently than from the menu .. but who knows, *Finder* can be weird.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because Finder pastes to the open folder, not the selected folder.

Comment: Then why is it that when a _file_ is selected that it is impossible to paste ?  Given what you say then the open folder is sufficient and it would know not to try to paste on top of that file!  Somehow _Finder_ chooses the worst of both worlds.

Comment: If you want to paste to the folder you clicked on, use column view. That's just the way it's always been. BTW, Windows does the same thing in list view, it's not a Mac trait exclusively.